# add protein code as identifier in regular expression search from UniProt

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I have secured the off file from UniProt with protein sequences of my interest and now I wish to extract/save the location of transmembrane region from the file.

the file looks like this

```
O75581  UniProtKB   Topological domain  1394    1613    .   .   .   Note=Cytoplasmic;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 

O75581  UniProtKB   Repeat  63  106 .   .   .   Note=LDL-receptor class B 1 

P13688  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   429 452 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 

P13688  UniProtKB   Topological domain  453 526 .   .   .   Note=Cytoplasmic;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 

P13688  UniProtKB   Domain  35  142 .   .   .   Note=Ig-like V-type;Ontology_term=ECO:0000250;evidence=ECO:0000250|UniProtKB:P31997 

P19022  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   725 745 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 

.....
```

To extract the location of transmembrane region and corresponding start end position, I have used following code

```
found = []
match = re.compile('(Transmembrane)'"\t"'(\w*)'"\t"'(\w*)')
with open("997_from uniprot.gff", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
j=len(searchlines)-1 
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines): 
    found.extend(match.findall(line))

col_Names=["location", "Start", "End"]
domain_position = pd.DataFrame(found,columns=col_Names)
domain_position.head()
```

which gives the desired result.

`+---+---------------+-------+------+
|   |   location    | Start | End  |
+---+---------------+-------+------+
| 0 | Transmembrane |  1371 | 1393 |
| 1 | Transmembrane |   429 |  452 |
| 2 | Transmembrane |   725 |  745 |
| 3 | Transmembrane |   646 |  668 |
| 4 | Transmembrane |   324 |  344 |
+---+---------------+-------+------+`

Now I wish to add the protein identifiers on each row of the table generated and I am aware `re.compile = '^(.*?)[ ]'` gives first word of the line, but I am not sure how to put this in my code without extracting unwanted lines?

Comment: Can you share a complete example of at least a few lines of the data? I thought there was an easier way of parsing that format, but I may be misremembering.

Comment: @AMC .. I could post my file due to limited space but here is how it nearly looks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_feature_format#GFF_general_structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may amend the regex as

```
match = re.compile('^(\S+).*?(Transmembrane)\t(\w*)\t(\w*)')
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

`^(\S+).*?` will match and capture the first non-whitespace chunk in a string and match any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few times as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent patterns.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nmuFW/1).

**NOTE**: Put back the quotes if needed, your input as shown in the question has no quotes.

Then, you just need to add the column:

```
col_Names=["proteinID", "location", "Start", "End"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to parse this file directly into a data frame:

```
domain = pd.read_csv('997_from uniprot.gff', sep='\t')
```

Now you can manipulate the dataframe any way you wish, for example to get the specific columns you want.

Comment: Thanks ! but the data in file is not uniformly distributed

Comment: @Kay According to [wikipedia](http://biowiki.org/wiki/index.php/Gff_Format): "GFF is relatively simple, containing just 9 fields per "feature" (record). Fields are tab-delimited and features are newline-delimited." So what I propose should work just fine.

Comment: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 10` this is the error is get, while trying to load it as data frame @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I figured a way to used these files as data frame now. I sorted my raw UniProt generated gff file, then used `grep "cellular location" uniprot.gff > newgff.txt`. Now this newgff is is good shape to be imported in tab separated data frame. Thanks!